# Expresión regular para caracteres repetidos

Tags: regex

Necesito una expresión regular que me valide una cadena de este tipo `"LMXJVSD"`. De momento la expresión regular que tengo es `[LMXJVSD]{1,7}`, esto me comprueba que solo aparezcan ese conjunto de caracteres, que como mínimo haya un caracter y como máximo 7. Bien pues quiero hacer que los caracteres no se repitan, y no sé cómo hacerlo.

El orden me da igual, por ejemplo:

> LMXL    -> incorrecto
>
> MXSD    -> correcto
>
> LMXJ    -> correcto
>
> LMXJVX  -> incorrecto

Answer (score 2):

Basado en su descripcion, una letra puede aparecer solo una vez en el resultado, y de acuerdo con el orden.

Asi, el expresion regular correcto es:
`L?M?X?J?V?S?D?`

Comment: Igual no me he expresado correctamente, el orden es indiferente. Como sería para no tener en cuenta el orden?

Comment: No es posible hacerlo con un expresion unico. Tiene que usar multiples expresiones o otros metodos (un program sencillo por ejemplo). Esta usando el regex en un lenguaje de programacion?

Comment: Si, lo estoy usando en Java

Comment: @Luke sí es posible

Answer (score 2):

Para caracteres que no se repitan, en cualquier orden

```
^(?:([LMXJVSD])(?!.*\1))+$
```

captura cada letra en el grupo 1, y verifica que no esté seguida por esa captura más adelante usando un lookahead negativo. Todo esto repetido 1 o más veces -en este caso `+` da lo mismo que `{1,7}`.

Cuando un grupo captura más de 1 vez, la última captura es la única que se mantiene (va sobreescribiendo), por eso puede ir comprobando que no esté seguido por `\1`.

Ejemplo en JavaScript

```js
const regex=/^(?:([LMXJVSD])(?!.*\1))+$/,
      t = document.getElementById('t'),
      r = document.getElementById('r');

t.addEventListener('input', () => {
    if (regex.test(t.value)) {
        r.innerText = 'Días de la semana en mayúscula';
    } else {
        r.innerText = 'Error';
    }
});
```

```html
<input id="t" type="text" value="LMXJVSD">
<div id="r">Días de la semana en mayúscula</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

He obtado por detectar si tiene un caracter repetido con regex, y el tamaño del texto lo pongo a prueba en el 'if'.

```js
const regex=/(.).*\1/;
t = document.getElementById('t');
r = document.getElementById('r');

t.addEventListener('input', () => {
    if (regex.test(t.value) && t.value.length>0 && t.value.length<8) {
        r.innerText = 'Incorrecto';
    } else {
        r.innerText = 'Correcto';
    }
});
```

```html
<input id="t" type="text" value="LMXJVSD">
<div id="r">Ingresa texto</div>
```